Setting TX power using iw and getting random values back
Using an AW-CB375NF (RTL8822CE) 2x2 M.2 WiFi card and trying to understand the different TX levels (in preparation for sending an embedded device for compliance testing), I can't make sense of the disparity in values I am supposedly setting, what iw reads back and more importantly what the Realtek test tool reports back.
What follows is the log of me setting the TX power using iw set txpower, reading it back again using iw info, then validating it using the Realtek test tool. All different!
0dBm:

# iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 0
# iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x1
        addr cc:47:40:3f:24:1f
        type managed
        wiphy 0
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 0.00 dBm

# ./rtwpriv wlan0 mp_get_txpower
wlan0    mp_get_txpower:patha=0,pathb=0
                        patha dBm=-3,pathb dBm=-3


1dBm:

# iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 100
# iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x1
        addr cc:47:40:3f:24:1f
        type managed
        wiphy 0
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 1.00 dBm

# ./rtwpriv wlan0 mp_get_txpower
wlan0    mp_get_txpower:patha=0,pathb=0
                        patha dBm=-2,pathb dBm=-2


5dBm:

# iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 500
# iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x1
        addr cc:47:40:3f:24:1f
        type managed
        wiphy 0
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 4.00 dBm

# ./rtwpriv wlan0 mp_get_txpower
wlan0    mp_get_txpower:patha=3,pathb=15
                        patha dBm=1,pathb dBm=1


10dBm:

# iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 1000
# iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x1
        addr cc:47:40:3f:24:1f
        type managed
        wiphy 0
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 9.00 dBm

# ./rtwpriv wlan0 mp_get_txpower
wlan0    mp_get_txpower:patha=23,pathb=35
                        patha dBm=6,pathb dBm=6


Maximum value allowed is 3174?:

# iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 3174
# iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x1
        addr cc:47:40:3f:24:1f
        type managed
        wiphy 0
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 15.00 dBm

# ./rtwpriv wlan0 mp_get_txpower
wlan0    mp_get_txpower:patha=32,pathb=44
                        patha dBm=9,pathb dBm=9


According to iw documentation, the values given to txpower are in millibel-milliwatts (mBm) instead of the commonly used decibel-milliwatts (dBm), for whatever reason.
<power in mBm> = 100 * <power in dBm>
As you can see, the value I provide for txpower, the value I get back from iw info and what the Realtek test tool reads back are all different. Using the maximum value set txpower allows as an example, which is the mystical value 3174, this supposedly translates to 15dBM for iw but the test tool reports back 9dBm...with an even more confusing mismatch between the RF channels: patha=32,pathb=44
There must be a logical explanation for this, but I can't find it. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The value you are reading back is -3 (negative 3) in your first example. Adding 1 dBm to that, as in your second example, gives -2. I would guess that the related tool is able to query some other setting in your network card and knows you have a -3dB antenna and is putting that value in to give your actual transmit power at the antenna rather than at the power amplifier output.

In any case it appears that -3 is your zero point as far as the realtek tool is concerned, all your other values are -3+4=1, -3+9=6 and so on.
